# Symmetry and non symmetry of matrices

Tags: matrices

Write A¤B if A is similar to B that is if there is is an invertible matrix p such that a equals B inverse BP. prove¤ is an equivalence relation on Square Matrices

Comment: There are three requirements for a relation to be called an "equivalence relation". Have you checked any of them?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What does the title of this question have to do with the question itself?

Answer (score 0):

$$A¤B \iff \exists_P: A=P^{-1}BP$$
Reflexive Property:
$$P=I \Longrightarrow A¤A$$
Symmetric Property:
$$A¤B \Longrightarrow \exists_P: A=P^{-1}BP, \quad \text{Let} \ Q=P^{-1} \Longrightarrow B=Q^{-1}AQ \Longrightarrow B¤A$$
Transitive Property:
$$A¤B \ \& \ B¤C \Longrightarrow \exists_{P,Q}: A=P^{-1}BP \ \& \ B=Q^{-1}CQ$$ $$\Longrightarrow A=P{-1}Q^{-1}CQP=(QP)^{-1}C(QP) \Longrightarrow A¤C$$